# The sequence $(a_n)_{n ∈ N}$ is given with $a_1=1$, $a_2=13$ and $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+6a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

To prove that:
$\sum_{i=1}^na_i = (3^{n+2}+(-2)^{n+2}-13)/6$, for every natural number $n \ge 1$.
I don't know how to start with...

Comment: Induction would be your safest bet

Comment: Yes I've done the induction for proving that $a_n = 3^n+(-2)^n, for n ≥ 1$ and got that $a_{k+2}=a_{k+1}+6a_{k} = 3^{k+2}+(-2)^{k+2}$, it was the previous request and now for this should I do induction for $a_1=1$, $a_2=13$ and $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+6a_n$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the characteristic function:
$$ x^2=x+6 $$ and we have two distinct eigenvalues, namely $ x_1=3, x_2=-2 $. Therefore, $$ a_n=C_13^{n}+C_2{(-2)}^n $$ where $ C_1, C_2 $ are two constants. Plug in the initial values, we get:
$$ \begin{cases}
a_1=3C_1 -2C_2=1\\
a_2=9C_1+4C_2=13
\end{cases} $$ 
Hence we have $$ \begin{cases}
C_1=1\\
C_2=1
\end{cases}\quad\text{and}\quad a_n=3^n+(-2)^n .$$

Thus $$ \begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^na_i&=\sum_{i=1}^n3^{i}+\sum_{i=1}^n(-2)^{i}\\
&=3\frac{3^n-1}{2}-2\frac{1-(-2)^n}{3}\\
&=\frac{3^{n+2}-9-4+(-2)^{n+2}}{6}\\
&=\frac{3^{n+2}+(-2)^{n+2}-13}{6}. \end{align}$$

Comment: I only needed the last part, the part after "Thus" so thank you very much.

Comment: And now how to prove that $_n ≡ 1 ( 6)$, for $n ≥ 1$. In general. Concrete I know how for example for $a_1 1 ≡ 1 ( 6)$, for $a_2 13 ≡ 1 ( 6)$...

Comment: @Viktor Use induction and note that $ a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+6a_n $.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The characteristic equation: $x^2-x - 6 = 0$ gives: $x = -2, 3$, thus the general solution is: $a_n = A\cdot (-2)^n + B\cdot 3^n$, and $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 13 \implies A = B = 1$. Thus $a_n = (-2)^n + 3^n$. Can you continue ? Can you find the *geometric* sums $\sum (-2)^n $, and $\sum 3^n$ ?

Comment: I stopped exactly here...I didn't realise at the moment that the sums were geometric. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The hint.
$$a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}=3(a_{n+1}+2a_n).$$
Thus, $$a_{n+1}+2a_n=15\cdot3^{n-1}=5\cdot3^n.$$
Now, use the telescoping sum.

Comment: Yes, but i can't use the telescoping sum because we should only use aritmethic and geometric sum.

Comment: @Viktor I used the sum of the geometric progression. See please better my hint. The telescoping sum it's nothing: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(x_{k+1}-x_k)=x_{n+1}-x_1.$

Comment: Thanks, I already solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Inductions a little arithmetic intensive but still doable.

The things to keep in mind is to use "strong" induction in the induction step so that you assume the proposition is true for all $n \le k$ and not just for $n = k$.

And the insight is that if the proposition is true for all $n\le k$ then

$a_k = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k a_i -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} a_i= \frac {3^{k+2} + (-2)^{k+2} - 13}6 -\frac {3^{k+1} + (-2)^{k+1} - 13}6 $.

And so the induction step becomes a matter of showing:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} a_i = $

$(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k a_i) + a_{k+1} =$

$ (\frac {3^{k+2} + (-2)^{k+2} - 13}6) + a_k + 6a_{k-1} = $

$(\frac {3^{k+2} + (-2)^{k+2} - 13}6) + (\frac {3^{k+2} + (-2)^{k+2} - 13}6 -\frac {3^{k+1} + (-2)^{k+1} - 13}6) + 6(\frac {3^{k+1} + (-2)^{k+1} - 13}6 -\frac {3^{k} + (-2)^{k} - 13}6)$

is equal to $\frac {3^{k+3} + (-2)^{k+3}-13}6$.

And that's just arithmetic.

(Note: That induction step assume the proposition is true for $a_k$, that $a_{k-1}$ exists, and that the proposition is true for $a_{k-1}$, and that $a_{k+1}$ is being defined as though $k+1 \ge 3$.  [In other words, the induction step is for $n=k\ge 2$.]  So for base cases you must show the proposition is true for $n=1;a_1$ and for $n=2;a_2$.)

(That's just a matter of plugging values in.)